# Android studio build error in hello world application

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, ide

I am trying to build basic hello world application in Android Studio following this thenewboston [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBsvRxJJOzG4r4k_zLKrnxl) on youtube. I created a new project with all the default settings. (Android API 14: Android 4.0 (IceCreamSandwich))

When I try to run application, I get the following errors:

Error:(7, 17)

> Resource id cannot be an empty string (at 'id' with value '@+id/').

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/abhinavmoudgil95/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

**Screenshot of error can be viewed [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8BnRAUnIoi4bjJ6a3MwbUZ0RkE/view).**

Following are the specifications:

- Android Studio 1.2.1.1
- Running on Macbook Pro OS X: 10.10.3 (Yosemite)
- BuildToolsVersion: 22.0.1

**Project Files:**

activity_main.xml

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

build.gradle (Project: MyApplication)

---

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abhinavmoudgil95.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

build.grade (Module: app)

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abhinavmoudgil95.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

I am completely new to android development. So please try to answer as simple as possible.

Comment: Remove this line android:id="@+id/" or change android:id="@+id/relativeLayout" from xml .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight modification:

You did not define id in `android:id="@+id/"` in **RelativeLayout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just a question out of curiosity:
 Do I have to do this in every project? and why default code in xml didn't work out?

Comment: When you use android:id="@+id/", you have to define unique id or else don't mention this property

Comment: It helps you to access certain component from xml in code by the unique id

Comment: @Abhinav if you double click on the design view it will automatically add this line to your root layout.

Comment: @NarenderNishad Sorry, I can't find design view. Can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: design view is shown when you click on 'Design' tab at the bottom next to 'Text'

Comment: @Abhinav in android studio where you design your mobile screen. There are two tab on the bottom with Design & Text. In Text View you can see xml code of your view. in Design you can see your actual screen. If you double click there then the android:id="@+id/" line is automatically added

Comment: @NarenderNishad Got it.

Answer (score 1):

When you define `android:id` preoperties to any `view` in xml then have to provide such unique id, So you can't leave blank id like which you have done in ur xml.

Remove this line :

```
android:id="@+id/"
```

OR

Add some unique id name :

```
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wish I could upvote your answer too :)